# Duda procedencia de operadores en Java división

Tags: java, operador

Porque en la operacion de Java `2*4/16` primero divide y luego multiplica siendo que también `16/2*4`, también divide y luego multiplica. No debería multiplicar y luego dividir según la prioridad del operador?

Comment: Realiza el mismo procedimiento a mano o en la calculadora y notarás que si esta multiplicando primero y luego dividiendo, lo que ocurre es que en ambos escenarios daría exactamente lo mismo hacer: 2 por 4 y eso dividirlo entre 16 que hacer: 4 entre 16 y eso multiplicarlo por 2

Comment: `(2 * 4) / 16 = 8 / 16 = .5` y `2 * (4 / 16) = 2 * .25 = .5`

Comment: Tienen la misma prioridad de precedencia, como indica la [especificación de Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17): *«The operators `*`, `/`, and `%` are called the multiplicative operators. The multiplicative operators **have the same precedence** and are syntactically left-associative (they group left-to-right).»*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Java tanto el operador `/` como el `*` tienen el mismo nivel de precedencia, la única manera de sobrescribir esto es usando paréntesis, por ejemplo `(2*4)/16` hará primero la multiplicación y luego la división.

Adjunto [mas informacion](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)

Comment: Muchas gracias. Buena info

Comment: _`(2*4)/16` hará primero la multiplicación y luego la división._ Y `2*4/16` también